# Applying predicate to an element in array

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I'm getting the following response from Postman...

```
"product_images": [
                {
                    "id": "973",
                    "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_1_image",
                    "is_default": "0"
                },
                {
                    "id": "988",
                    "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_10_image",
                    "is_default": "0"
                },
                {
                    "id": "989",
                    "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_11_image_1507874590",
                    "is_default": "1"
                }
            ]
```

Now I want to apply a predicate and add to my array only that image with an `is_default` value of 1. So in this case just the last image will be added. So how can I achieve this...? Hope somebody can help...

As of now all images are added to the array and that I'm doing like so...

```
var productImages :[ProductImage] = []
        if let images = anItem["product_images"] as? [[String:String]]
        {
          for image in images {
            guard let imageId = image["id"],
                  let url1 = image["image"],
                  let isDefaultValue = image["is_default"] else {continue}
                  print(imageId)
                 let productImage = ProductImage(id: imageId, url: URL(string: url1)!, isDefault: (Int(isDefaultValue) ?? 0) != 0)                        
                productImages.append(productImage)
            }}

        let theProduct = Product(name: name, id: id, theRate: rate, quantity: qty, sku: skuCode, prdCateg: prodCat, prodDescr: description, images: productImages, mrp: mrp)

        self.productData1.append(theProduct)
```

Comment: You can filter array based on your condition.

Comment: save all the dictionary in your array after that traverse your array from first index and check is default value is 0 or 1 if it is zero then drop the element from array at the end you have an array with is default value 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply `productImage.isDefault` value before appending to `productImages` array:

```
if let images = anItem["product_images"] as? [[String:String]]
{
    for image in images {
        guard let imageId = image["id"],
              let url1 = image["image"],
              let isDefaultValue = image["is_default"] else {continue}

        print(imageId)

        let productImage = ProductImage(id: imageId, url: URL(string: url1)!, isDefault: (Int(isDefaultValue) ?? 0) != 0)

        // just add a simple check here:
        if productImage.isDefault == 1 {
            productImages.append(productImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmad F. It worked! But `true` had to be used instead of `1`

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

You can achieve it one line of code

In swift 3 You can use filter instead of predicate

`let productsWithDefaultImage = productImages.filter{$0.isDefault == 1}`

Solution 2

As Ahmed Suggest  Just copy and paste it

```
  var productImages :[ProductImage] = []
    if let images = anItem["product_images"] as? [[String:String]]
    {
      for image in images {
        guard let imageId = image["id"],
              let url1 = image["image"],
              let isDefaultValue = image["is_default"],
              isDefaultValue == "1" else {continue}
              print(imageId)
             let productImage = ProductImage(id: imageId, url: URL(string: url1)!, isDefault: (Int(isDefaultValue) ?? 0) != 0)                        
            productImages.append(productImage)
        }}

    let theProduct = Product(name: name, id: id, theRate: rate, quantity: qty, sku: skuCode, prdCateg: prodCat, prodDescr: description, images: productImages, mrp: mrp)

    self.productData1.append(theProduct)
```

Comment: .@Jon Snow doing so gave the error...`Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and 'String'`

Comment: Ok..so will it consider `true` as 1..?

Comment: @User.bw Sorry My bad please use 1 Instead

Comment: Why to do such a filter *after* generating the array?! based on the OP code, you could check it while iterating in the `images` array.

Comment: @JonSnow doing so still gave the error `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and 'Int'`

Comment: Ok @User.bw If in your `ProductImage` Class `isDefault` is bool then use true or if isDefault is Int then use 1 :)

Comment: Thanks @JonSnow..thanks for the inputs. Have given an upvote...:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working playground that illustrates what you could do

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


let productImages: [[String:String]] = [
    [
    "id": "973",
    "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_1_image",
    "is_default": "0"
    ],
    [
    "id": "988",
    "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_10_image",
    "is_default": "0"
    ],
    [
    "id": "989",
    "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_11_image_1507874590",
    "is_default": "1"
    ]
]

let productsWithDefaultImage = productImages.filter {

    if let is_default: String = $0["is_default"] {
        if is_default == "1" {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is always only **one** `default` image use the `first` function

```
var productImages = [ProductImage]()
if let images = anItem["product_images"] as? [[String:String]]
{
     if let defaultImage = images.first(where: {$0["is_default"] == "1"}) {
        let productImage = ProductImage(id: defaultImage["id"]!, 
                                       url: URL(string: defaultImage["image"]!)!, 
                                 isDefault: true)                        
        productImages.append(productImage)
     }
...
```

---

**Edit**

This is a stand-alone version to be tested in a Playground

```
struct ProductImage {
    let id : String
    let url : URL
    let isDefault : Bool
}

let images = [
    ["id": "973", "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_1_image", "is_default": "0"],
    ["id": "988", "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_10_image", "is_default": "0"],
    ["id": "989", "image": "http://sellerapp.binaryicdirect.com/public/uploads/products/263_22_11_image_1507874590", "is_default": "1"]
]

var productImages = [ProductImage]()
if let defaultImage = images.first(where: {$0["is_default"] == "1"}) {
    let productImage = ProductImage(id: defaultImage["id"]!,
                                    url: URL(string: defaultImage["image"]!)!,
                                    isDefault: true)
    productImages.append(productImage)
}
print(productImages)
```

Comment: .@vadian..what is your opinion about the accepted answer...?

Comment: I don't judge accepted answers if I provided an alternative in the same question.

Comment: Ok @vadian No problem. But I did try your solution also. But in this line `     let url1 = image["image"],` its throwing an error saying `Expected expression in conditional`

Comment: My code doesn't use `url1`. The optional binding expression `if let defaultImage = ... { ... }` is supposed to replace the entire loop.

Comment: Did make the correction @vadian but even those images are taken whose default value is 0 while only those with a default value of 1 should have been taken(or added to the array)..

Comment: The code filters the image with `is_default == 1`, creates the `ProductImage` and appends it to the `productImages` array. I updated the answer with a stand-alone version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158501/discussion-between-user-bw-and-vadian).